# ListFragment doesnt get refreshed when i open it after visiting other Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a Main Activity and then 4 Fragments:

Home - Just a normal home page
About - Basic info about app, 
ListUsers - list total users with filtering (this also have actionTabs) and 
Contact - Contact info.

When i start my application it lands on Home Fragment and then i click on the list users which is implemented with tabs, i can switch tabs and it works fine and shows proper data.

After navigating from ListUsers to and other fragment and coming back to ListUsers, i realized that it doesnt changes the data and shows the same data for multiple tabs.

ListUsersFragment Code in onCreateView :

```
public classListUsers extends ListFragment implements TabListener {

  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getActivity().setTitle("Users");
            mActivity = getActivity();
            actionBar = mActivity.getActionBar();

            filterUsers = getUsers(1);
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(mActivity, filterUsers);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            Tab firstTab = actionBar.newTab();
            RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.firstLabel, null);
            firstTab.setCustomView(view);
            actionBar.addTab(firstTab.setTabListener(this));
            .. Similarly addd 2 more tabss..

           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listusers, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }


    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
            filterUsers.clear();
            filterUsers = getUsers(arg0.position());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

    public List<User> getUsers(int pos) {
       // Here i return the list of users which is changing based on selection and return list of users
     }
}
```

Comment: does `filterUsers` change when you come back again and select different tab? i mean does `filterUsers = getUsers(arg0.position());` change your varaible?

Comment: no it remains in the same state which i left last time..

Comment: I don't think you are implementing your tabs incorrectly. The host `Activity` should be responsible for creating the tabs instead of this `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Tablistener, but I have beat myself over the head over problems with listview enough times to have a clue what you are doing wrong here. Remember that you have to refresh the adapter and attach it to the listview everytime you change something. Try changing the function below and let me know if it works out for you.

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        filterUsers.clear();
        filterUsers = getUsers(arg0.position());
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(mActivity, filterUsers);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your logic of program has some issues: every time you create the listfragment you add 3 tabs to your ACTIONBAR OF ACTIVITY, for example for the first time you add 1,2,3 and after going to other fragments and commimg back you add 3 fragments other than 1,2,3 to your activity say 4,5,6 but 1,2,3 are still there with a little problem that their listener which is your previous listfragment is now deleted, so tab 1,2,3 dose not have any listener now and clicking on them gives you no result. i think if you scroll the tabs you may find 6 tabs now in the actionbar but you think you have just 3tabs. change your logic or use other tab mechanism for your listfragment. for example use tabhost for Listfragment layout. or use FragmentTabHost, instead, or you can set tag for your tabs and remove them in onDestroy method of your listFragment.